# How to link api with my website?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, frontend

How to link my website with books database like ISBNDB.com, so when a user search's for a book, he can get the imgae and description of the book. I'm developing a website for selling book and using Google Firebase as the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Cloud Functions for Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Using Cloud Functions, you can populate your database with the API response from the backend, and users can interact / search for books that way.

However, if you are wanting to do that client-side and push the results up to the database, call the API from there instead.

Hope this helps to get you started